ASP.NET Core 9, SmtpMail with self.signed certificate
In .NET 8 we can use:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (
        object s,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
    )
    {
        return true;
    };

to allow SmtpMail with servers that use a self-signed certificate. ServicePointManager however is deprecated since .NET 9.
How can I deal with a local SmtpServer, which is self-signed, in .NET 9?

Migration chart

What you posted doesn't allow self-signed certificates, it disables certificate validation completely. The real solution would be to trust the certificate, not disable validation. Right now anyone between you and the server (eg an unscrupulous cafe owner) can intercept your calls using their own self-signed certificate on their router

I know, that's only for internal use and it's a bad technique. By the way that works in .NET 9 too. I tested it. For real life you will have a SMPT Server with a Certificate to trust (hopefully)
